# Проблема в коде(не знаю как описать)

Tags: python

Здраствуйте, я пытался выполнить 1 задачу там где мы получаем список с чисел и при сложении их должно выйти число равное k, но у меня почему возрощяет пустой список.

Примичание! (числа не должни быть одинаковыми при сложении)

```
def twoSum(nums, k):
for i in nums:
    i += 1
    for j in nums:
        j = i + 1
        if (nums[i] + nums[j]) == k: 
            return [nums[i], nums[j]]   
        else: 
            return []
            

num = [0, 1, 3, 4]
k = 5

print(twoSum(num, k))
```

Зарание спасибо!

Comment: в ваших циклах for i и j  - это элементы списка, а не индексы. Используйте range, и второй цикл начинайте с i+1, чтобы не было повторов

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer  при использовании range

Comment: @Эникейщик Если вы имеете в виду, что лучше for in использовать - то как элементарными средствами  избежать образования пар их одного и того же элемента? (ну не привлекая zip и т.д.)

Comment: @MBo я этот случай не учел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я правильно понял, задача состоит в проверке на то, есть ли в списке два числа, которые в сумме дают некое число k.
И я так подозреваю, вы хотели перебирать в переменных i и j индексы, но для этого нужно писать не `for i in nums`, а `for i in range(len(nums) - 1):`. И зачем вы потом прибавляете единицу не очень понятно. Плюс вы возвращаете пустой список сразу после того, как первая пара не подошла, хотя вы ещё не проверили остальные.
Исправленная версия:

```
def twoSum(nums, k):
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        for j in range (i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == k: 
                return [nums[i], nums[j]]
    return []
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если считаете, что ответ правильный, то отметьте его таковым слева от ответа галочкой

Answer (score 1):

```
def twoSum(nums, k):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            if (nums[i] + nums[j]) == k: 
                return [nums[i], nums[j]]   
    return []
```